# Difference in use-cases for just using '.catch' v.s using 'Throw Error...' with '.catch'

Tags: javascript, error-handling

If `.catch` catches any errors upon request attempt, why would I need to use `Throw Error...` with `.catch`?

For instance, what is the `throw Error` used for, that the `.catch` doesn't handle automatically?

```
fetch(...).then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(...)
        } else {
          response.json().then((responseData) => {
            ...
              }
            }
          })
        }
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error)
      })
```

Comment: Could you please give an example? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @DanWilson Updated with example

Comment: Does the `fetch` function already check `if (!response.ok)` before fulfilling the Promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (!response.ok) { throw Error(...)` gives you an opportunity to provide a specific error message when the response has a status code other than 200.

You could even switch on the status code and provide different messaging for 404 or 500 errors.

The lower `.catch()` is simple a catch-all for any exceptions that may occur while handling the response. If `response.json()` blows up due to some deserialization issue then `.catch()` will log an error to the console for you.